# Wrap each english letter in div with class="en"

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to wrap each English letter/word in a specific div with `<span class="en">` to change font in this letters/Words.

This is my code. It isn't working at all
What is the bug? What should I fix?

```
var newhtml = [];

$.each($('.ItemDescription p').text().split(' '), function(i, text) {
    var alphabet = text.split("");
    $.each(alphabet, function(letter) {
        if (app.englishExp.test(letter)) {
            newhtml.push("</span><span class='en'>");
        }
        newhtml.push(letter);
    });
});

$('.ItemDescription p').text(newhtml);
```

thanks Liron.

Comment: Instead of saying it isn't working, tell us what it's doing vs expected behavior. Also you say you want to wrap it in a div, but I see you wrapping it in a span and I don't see anything that changes the font. Please include a more complete example, possibly include a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `join` the newhtml array otherwise you would be dumping that directly.

```
$('.ItemDescription p').html(newhtml.join(''));
```

Replace

```
if (app.englishExp.test(letter)) {
            newhtml.push("</span><span class='en'>");
        }
        newhtml.push(letter);
```

with

```
if (app.englishExp.test(letter)) {
      newhtml.push("<span class='en'>" + letter + "</span>");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a span with a language attribute? I know that isn't what he's asking for, but it would be valid HTML.